# What is the formal term/process for writing down a design?

Tags: drafting

I forgot what all of it is called but there's this specific way you draw the different components of a device or machine, kind of like blue prints but on plain write paper. You break the device down into larger pieces and draw each piece orthographically from like 3 different perspectives with labels and uncertainty in measurement requirements and all that, very standard. Anyone got a clue?

Answer (score 3):

The process of creating an *[engineering drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_drawing)* is called either *[technical drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_drawing)* or *drafting*. How to draw is covered under the standard *ISO 128*.

The separate drawings from different directions are called *views*, how to use views is covered in exacting detail in standard *ISO 128-30* and *128-34*.  number of views and choice of views is governed by desire to use of as few views as possible while describing object without ambiguity, with following principles in mind:

- avoiding the use of hidden lines,
- avoiding repeating same thing.

As such you do not need three views, when one is sufficient. This commonly happens in rotationally symmetrical objects as well as when cutting sheets.

**Note**: A blueprint is just a residue of how the technical drawings were copied, originals were most likely black on white or black on translucent (to make the pencil drawing or previous original used as guide easy to see). The technical drawing standards does not specify color.

Comment: "Drafting" is usually a pretty safe bet for the term to use there.

Answer (score 1):

First angle projection, third angle projection and isometric projection spring to mind - all types of drawing layouts.

The name "Blue print" comes from the copying of the final original for production or use - the type of copying that was available back in the day. Now that full colour copiers exist the term still hangs around.